# How to use navigator onchange event in RxJS stream

Tags: typescript, rxjs

Here I am trying to write a nice observable to get navigator permissions. The problem is that it updates the status with onchange event. I tried to use FromEvent, but it doesn't look neat. Any nice ideas how to implement it?

```
getState$(name: PermissionName): Observable<PermissionState> {
  return from(this.navigator.permissions.query({ name })).pipe(
    map((permissionStatus: PermissionStatus) => {
      // How to use onchange callback into stream
      permissionStatus.onchange = function() {
        console.log('permission state has changed to ', this.state);
      };
      return permissionStatus.state
    })
  );
}
```

After a bit of playing I found that this is **possible solution**

```
getState(name: PermissionName): Observable<PermissionState> {
  return from(this.navigator.permissions.query({ name })).pipe(
    mergeMap((permissionStatus: PermissionStatus) => {
      return fromEvent(permissionStatus, 'change').pipe(
        map(event => event?.target?.['state'] as PermissionState),
        startWith(permissionStatus.state)
      );
    })
  )
}
```

And yet wanna fount a better one

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a subject to subscribe to the event. The query only returns a Promise. An observable created from a promise will only return a single value (or an error).

Iterating from what you came up with, here is an improvement

```
const getState = (name: PermissionName): Observable<PermissionState> => {
  return from(navigator.permissions.query({ name })).pipe(
    switchMap((permissionStatus: PermissionStatus) => {
      return fromEvent(permissionStatus, 'change').pipe(
        map(() => permissionStatus.state),
        startWith(permissionStatus.state)
      );
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @Matthieu. But there are better solutions to this problem. Without any additional variables. For example have a look at my one above. But still it can be better, I think.

Comment: What's bothering you with the solution you found ?

Comment: Please see my edit on the slight improve I can suggest.